# How can i delete an object in a array?

Tags: javascript, web

I have a problem for delete an Object in an array.
I think the solution is very simple but I am not good in javascript.

[This is my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7WEX.png)

I want to delete the **value** in this array but I have a problem because of its something like that in js:

```
myArray = [Object1,Object2,...]
```

and in the object

```
Object1 = {SUM: "-0.75" , mont: "1", name: "test", **value: "{"25":"test"}**, year: "2017"}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the right element of the array and and the property of the object with a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) and the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator.

```
delete myArray[0].value;
//^^^^                   delete operator
//     ^^^^^^^           array
//            ^^^        index of array
//                ^^^^^  property
```

Answer (score 0):

var Arr = [{value:"xyz",name:"ajhs"},{value:"xyz",name:"jask"}]

delete(Arr[1].value)

this will delete value from object at index 1

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use several methods to remove an item from it:
//1
someArray.shift(); // first element removed
//2
someArray = someArray.slice(1); // first element removed
//3
someArray.slice(0,1); // first element removed
//4
 someArray.pop(); // last element removed

if you want to remove element at position x, use:
someArray.slice(x,1);
```

Comment: funny, i think it is to remove a property of the object, not to remove an element of the array ...

Answer (score -1):

```
myArray = [Object1,Object2,...]
If you want to remove element at position ,     
myArray .splice(indexPosition,1);
```

Comment: thank, for your answers but is for remove property of the object in my array, not to remove an element of the array

Comment: to remove property in array used:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete